# Need Steps to upgrade Xcode / OS level in mac ?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don't know about IOS development , But I started learning that IOS development , I have mac in which I have 6.0 iphone simulator , 6.0 ipad simulator .I thing 6.0 is OS version ? may I correct ?
Now I want to download 7.0 simulator with iphone/ipad on my mac and 5.0

Can you please give me step where I download and give me a link ?

Actually I my friend given Xcode in which in build  6.0 os simulator come.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to code for iOS7 you'll ned Xcode 5.

If you want Xcode 5, you'll need OSX 10.8.

First thing to do, click on the little Apple icon in the top left of your screen:

[image]

Click `About this Mac` and make sure you have OSX 10.8.x.

If not, you'll have to order it from the App Store (£13.99 in the UK).

After that download the latest version Xcode from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: thank I have 10.8 OSX but which button i will click so that it start downloadling

Comment: can you share the image of button from where I download

Comment: Click the word "Apple" in my answer.

Comment: then I click view in mac app store then ?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from there.

Comment: Sir Actually I am looking you link on window .may be that is reason I am not able to download ?

Comment: After click mac app store this button what to do next so that my downloading start ?

Comment: You have to be on OSX 10.8.x to download it. It won't install on Windows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38164/discussion-between-user944513-and-robert)

Answer (score 1):

Get the new Xcode from here(If you dont have a Xcode5).

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Once you have the new xcode Goto Xcode -> preferences -> Downloads 
You should be able to find the latest simulator to download from there.

Comment: in this Xcode 7.0 simulator is inbuild

Comment: Is it possible 2 xcode in same mac

Comment: @user944513 Yes you can have 2Xcodes in the same mac.

Answer (score 1):

Get Xcode 5.0 from the Mac App Store. This is the best way, as you will get updates automatically.

You can have two Xcode versions, just have to put them in different folders.

Xcode 5 has simulators for iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: how to get os 5 simulators .?

Comment: You need Xcode 4.6.3 for that.